# python pandas operations on columns

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I would like to know the best way to do operations on columns in python using pandas.

I have a classical database which I have loaded as a dataframe, and I often have to do operations such as for each row, if value in column labeled 'A' is greater than x then replace this value by column'C' minus column 'D'

for now I do something like

```
for i in len(df.index):
    if df.ix[i,'A'] > x :
        df.ix[i,'A'] = df.ix[i,'C'] - df.ix[i, 'D']
```

I would like to know if there is a simpler way of doing these kind of operations and more importantly the most effective one as I have large databases

I had tried without the for i loop, like in R or Stata, I was advised to use "a.any" or "a.all" but I did non find anything either here or in the pandas docs.

Thanks by advance.

Comment: The code has an error: len(df.index) returns an integer number which cannot be iterated.
It would correct to do 
    for i in range(0, len(df.index))
in order iterate the dataframe

Answer (score 7):

You can just use a boolean mask with either the `.loc` or `.ix` attributes of the DataFrame.

```
mask = df['A'] > 2
df.ix[mask, 'A'] = df.ix[mask, 'C'] - df.ix[mask, 'D']
```

If you have a lot of branching things then you can do:

```
def func(row):
    if row['A'] > 0:
        return row['B'] + row['C']
    elif row['B'] < 0:
        return row['D'] + row['A']
    else:
        return row['A']

df['A'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

`apply` should generally be much faster than a for loop.

Comment: Actually I have several conditions : if df.['A'] == 999 ; if df['A'] < 999 and df['B'] == 999 and so on... I am not sure how this boolean extends

Comment: This example you provided is: `(df['A'] == 999) & (df['B'] == 999)`, But if you have a branches with else statement also you should use `apply` along the asix.

Comment: That indeed works for some of my cases, thanks for that ; but in others I have to consider actual different values, for instance for categorical variables : row['A'] == 1 then A1, row['A'] ==2 then A2, row['A'] == 3 then A3 and so on.

Comment: I added an example to the answer that covers that case (using `apply`).

Answer (score 7):

simplest according to me.

```
from random import randint, randrange, uniform
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':randrange(0,10),'b':randrange(10,20),'c':np.random.randn(10)})

#If colC > 0,5, then ColC = ColB - Cola 
df['c'][df['c'] > 0.5] = df['b'] - df['a']
```

Tested, it works.

```
a   b   c
2  11 -0.576309
2  11 -0.578449
2  11 -1.085822
2  11  9.000000
2  11  9.000000
2  11 -1.081405
```

Comment: it works well ! but it returns a warning at the first execution: `>>> df['c'][df['c'] > 0.5] = df['b'] - df['a']
__main__:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of ways of doing this, but here's the pattern I find easiest to read.

```
#Assume df is a Panda's dataframe object
idx = df.loc[:, 'A'] > x
df.loc[idx, 'A'] = df.loc[idx, 'C'] - df.loc[idx, 'D']
```

Setting the elements less than x is as easy as df.loc[~idx, 'A'] = 0

Answer (score 0):

Start with..

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':randrange(1,10),'b':randrange(10,20),'c':np.random.randn(10)})
a   b   c
0   7   12  0.475248
1   7   12  -1.090855
2   7   12  -1.227489
3   7   12  0.163929
```

end with...

```
df.ix[df.A < 1,df.A = df['c'] - df['d']]; df
    a   b   c
0   7   12  5.000000
1   7   12  5.000000
2   7   12  5.000000
3   7   12  5.000000
4   7   12  1.813233
```

Comment: sorry but this leads to a syntax error : `>>> df.ix[df.A < 1,df.A = df['c'] - df['d']]; df
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    df.ix[df.A < 1,df.A = df['c'] - df['d']]; df
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`